# C# MVC modify View HTML before rendering on browser

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I was wondering if it is possible to modify a view HTML before sending it to the browser.

I wanted to create a custom tag compiler where i can insert a simple tag as `<my-parsing-tag></my-parsing-tag>` on the view and replace it for some specific HTML.

I'm already using `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted` filters to execute some actions on the context (Change ViewBags, View names, Sessions, etc.), i also tried to do it there but i couldn't find the correct place to get the HTML, well i don't even know if it's possible to do so.

Is it possible or i would need to store my views HTML on the database to accomplish what i need ?

**EDIT**

As @Juan asked, why i need it:

I'm working with a call to action system where the user can place some specific modal campaigns on the page he wants just using those simple tags or selecting the page that will display it.

After that i will append the selected HTML to the view before sending it to the user. This system is intended for users that can't work editing the views since they don't work with HTML.

**EDIT 2**

After some research i have tried to implement a custom `RazorView`, the code is [here](https://pastebin.com/rZZXsvza) with the Index View HTML, but now i have two problems:

The first one is that my Index View has some HTML that is coming from the database and is placed there using vars on my ViewModel and instead of the call to action HTML being placed at the end of my Index View, it's being placed before the ViewModel vars. The second problem is that the HTML is being duplicated instead of replaced. Here is an image of how the result looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPKLM.jpg

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? What is it exactly that you need to do with your "custom" tags?

Comment: @Juan, i have updated my question with the explanation.

Comment: Does that mean that the user will type that into a field somewhere and you replace it at runtime? I am not sure I understand.

Comment: Assuming the use case is what Juan is saying, you can use Extension methods on HtmlHelper and use TagBuilder to manipulate the view as you like - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs

Comment: @Juan, I will have an admin page where the user will select the page he wants to include lets say a newsletter form, the user can select the Home page from a combo box or he can edit the View and include the custom tag. If i work with the first option or second option i need to edit the HTML response and include the form before sending it to the browser

Comment: @vabii, that could work but i still need to know how to do it dynamically, where in the response context i will include the created HTML to the user

Comment: @Terkhos, it depends upon what info you are capturing from user on your admin system. If user just supplies you a page and tag, you will have to assume where to insert that tag. You are trying to create a kind of CMS, more info you gather from user on admin, more accurate you will know where to insert it in your view. As you mentioned, storing views in you db is one option so it can be directly updated from admin system.

Comment: I understand better now. Thanks!

Comment: @vabii, i already have where to put the extra HTML on the view, this is the easy part, the hard on is to modify the original html parser and include what i need + a database query to get the call to action form to be included. I'm trying to work with a custom ViewEngine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an HtmlHelper extension for this:

http://tech.trailmax.info/2012/08/creating-custom-html-helper-in-mvc3/

I would suggest the following:

- Define a container in your template (layout most likely) that will receive any content the user decides to "drop" into it via the admin panel.
- You let the view know there is something to display via the ViewBag.
- The view uses information you passed in order to render the desired content.

How it renders is where the HTMLHelper extensions come in. You could create an extension method which renders partial views based on the information you pass to it or maybe a set of extension methods that you call selectively based on the desired widget.

Comment: That could work but i'm not always going to drop the user HTML at the bottom, it can be placed anywhere in the page, that's why the need of the `<my-parsing-tag></my-parsing-tag>`, also is that going to intercept the parsed view html ?

Comment: That's OK. Instead of dropping the custom tag, drop the call to the HtmlHelper extension.

Comment: that didn't really work for me, i couldn't manage to get it to work on the parsed HTML and inject it back to the user, do you have any working example?